# Pythonic proportion calculation of two conditions

Tags: python

Here's a really simple question regarding pythonic coding.

Given a list, if you want to calculate the proportion of items satisfying (A and B), out of those satisfying (A), a natural solution would be:

Imagine the list is of integers, condition A is (>3), condition B is (>5)

```
count = 0
correct = 0

for item in items:
  if item > 3:
    count += 1

    if item > 5:
      correct += 1

score = float(correct) / count
print '%.2f' % score
```

An alternative solution:

```
count = len([1 for i in items if i > 3])
correct = len([1 for i in items if i > 5])

score = float(correct) / count
print '%.2f' % score
```

The alternative looks sexier to me, though it loops through items twice and is not efficient. Is there an accepted pythonic solution to this common scenario or is the first solution good enough?

Thanks.

Comment: (I'm finding it harder and harder to take people who say "Pythonic" seriously, especially when they use it three times in a row...)

Comment: I don't quite know what _pythonic_ is, but building lists for counting should not be it.

Comment: I think it's open to interpretation.. My take on it is an elegance in code that can be achieved by using unique traits of the python language, thus enabling expressions that would not be possible in other languages, or that would look ugly. I guess it is trying to reach the ultimate balance between readability, conciseness and performance.

Comment: No arguments there on my part. But a solution that is aready solved in O(N) time and O(0) space should be preferred to one that uses O(N) space, even if the latter seems nicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your (alternate) solution is great, except for this small change:

```
count = sum(1 for i in items if i > 3)
correct = sum(1 for i in items if i > 5)

score = float(correct) / count
print '%.2f' % score
```

The syntax that looks like a list comprehension without the brackets is called a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

I'm not aware of any readable way to get a solution without iterating over the list twice, other than the one you already have. I'd still go with the solution above,  unless a **profiler** tells me I have to speed this up.

Comment: Btw, because I always wanted to use complex numbers at least once: `s = sum(complex(x>3,x>5) for x in items); score = float(s.real)/s.imag` ;-)

Comment: `count = sum(i > 3 for i in items)`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a general solution, but one based on your question and the sample answer.

If you know the relationship between the two conditions, then you don't have to traverse the sequence twice:

```
gt3 = [x for x in items if x > 3]
count = len(gt3)
correct = sum(x > 5 for x in gt3)
```

An efficient, more general, and still pythonic solution could be:

```
count, correct = map(sum, zip(*((x > 3, x > 5) for x in items)))
```

The conditions of greater than 3 and 5 can be replaced by any other conditions.

Comment: I know about zip versus izip, but it would be out of context.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby
li={x:len(list(y))for x,y in groupby(l,lambda x:2 if x>5 else 1 if x>3 else 0)}
print(li[2]/(li[1]+li[2]))
```

python3.1

Comment: You don't want to create a list of ones to count something.

Comment: I think that one of the reasons to add generator expressions to the language was to help avoid the use of the anonymous and verbose lambda functions.